# Wallpaper doesn't appear

Tags: desktop-background

After I upgraded Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04, the wallpaper doesn't appear anymore. In instead, apeears a blank image. I already tried to change, but nothing happens.

Also, I already tried in Gnome 3 and Unity, and the problem persists.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

System Settings - Appearance - Wallpapers: you can choose a default wallpaper from 13.04.
Also the default wallpapers from 12.10 are still available.

Comment: I also tried this, but this not solved my problem.

Comment: The directory /usr/share/backgrounds contains the wallpaper images. Does this directory exist and does it contain wallpapers?